# Is it possible to show an Ant Design Tooltip conditionally only when the content has ellipsis?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using the Ant Design component `<Paragraph>` to show a text with a variable size, and I use the ellipsis option to show "..." when that text exceeds the length of its container.

I also added a `<Tooltip>` to that `<Paragraph>` to show the entire text when it is collapsed:

```
<Tooltip title="This text is displayed, so I don't want to show a tooltip.">
  <Paragraph ellipsis>
    This text is displayed, so I don't want to show a tooltip.
  </Paragraph>
</Tooltip>
```

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to know when the ellipsis appears on the paragraph, so my Tooltip is always shown.

[image: tooltip-shows-on-a-fully-displayed-text]

Is it possible to show an Ant Design Tooltip only when the content has been affected by the ellipsis option?

Comment: Yes it is possible, can i write a solution using material-ui ? I dont know antdesign

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ant Design v4.2.0 made that possible by adding an "onEllipsis" function to the "ellipsis" object.

[TooltipParagraph API](https://ant.design/components/typography/#Typography.Paragraph)

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-conditional-tooltip-yuxx5?file=/src/TooltipParagraph.tsx)

```
const TooltipParagraph: React.FC<ParagraphProps> = ({
  children,
  ellipsis,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [truncated, setTruncated] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Tooltip title={truncated ? children : undefined}>
      <Paragraph
        {...props}
        ellipsis={{ ...ellipsis, onEllipsis: setTruncated }}
      >
        {/* NOTE: Fragment is necessary to avoid showing the title */}
        <>{children}</>
      </Paragraph>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};
```

Comment: Also an elegant way to conditionally add a Tooltip to an element (based on custom logic).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about antdegin, But I faced this problem once and I was able to resolve it.

To know if an text tag has overflown this check will be truthy:

`element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth`.

I tried to think about a generic way to solve this issue and ended up with this component (this is not production ready!)

```
function SmartText({
  TypographyComponent = "h1",
  TypographyComponentProps = {},
  TooltipComponent = ({ children }) => children, // just for demo purpose, it will do nothing basically if not passed
  ToolTipComponentProps = {},
  children = ""
}) {
  const textComponentRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [tooltipTitle, setTooltipTitle] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (
      textComponentRef.current &&
      textComponentRef.current.offsetWidth <
        textComponentRef.current.scrollWidth
    ) {
      setTooltipTitle(textComponentRef.current.innerText);
    }
  }, [children]);

  return (
    <TooltipComponent {...ToolTipComponentProps} title={tooltipTitle}>
      <TypographyComponent {...TypographyComponentProps} ref={textComponentRef}>
        {children}
      </TypographyComponent>
    </TooltipComponent>
  );
}
```

The `TypographyComponent` in your case is the `Paragraph`, to use this method, the TypographyComponent has to forward the ref or to support it.

I used the `SmartText` with @material-ui tooltip like this:

```
<SmartText
  TypographyComponentProps={{
    style: {
      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      maxWidth: 500,
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      overflow: "hidden",
      textAlign: "left"
    }
  }}
  TooltipComponent={Tooltip}
  ToolTipComponentProps={{
    placement: "right"
  }}
>
  Tooltip is needed because this text is long
</SmartText>
<SmartText
  TypographyComponentProps={{
    style: {
      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      maxWidth: 300,
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      overflow: "hidden",
      textAlign: "left"
    }
  }}
  TooltipComponent={Tooltip}
  ToolTipComponentProps={{
    placement: "right"
  }}
>
  No tooltip needed
</SmartText>
```

Finally, here is [working codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-butterfly-gzs7z)

Comment: Thanks for your help Mohamed! I'm currently working on an Ant Design solution for this, and I think I can use your solution! However, I can't make it run properly, because I'm getting `null` in the `textComponentRef = React.useRef(null)` line, as you can see in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-and-antdesing-paragraph-ellipsis-fxwjm?file=/index.js). Do you have an idea why in my example is not capturing the ref?

Comment: I just looked at andtd [implementation of Paragraph](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/typography/Paragraph.tsx) in github, it does not forward the ref and a message in your sandbox in the console saying that functions cannot have ref and that they must forwardRef

Comment: When i looked also at Title and Text, they do not forward the ref neither. I think it is problematic and antd should review this and support the forwardRef because it is important in this case. All of Typography components are returning a Base class component which is not exported. If it was exported we could've done the trick