# Show Tooltip in Table cells with Ellipsis: Ant Desing

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, antd, ellipsis

I use the Ant Design library to render the Table and Tooltip components. If you specify in the table column settings:

```
ellipsis: {
    showTitle: false,
},
```

```
render: (value) => (
    <Tooltip placement="top" title={value}>
        <span>{value}</span>
    </Tooltip>
),
```

Then when you hover over a table cell, the tooltip will be displayed.

[Open an image with an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30xWH.jpg)

How do I make the tooltip display only if there are ellipses? If there are no ellipses, then the tooltip is not displayed.

I tried using useState, but it works perfectly for only one html element, and I have a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **Typography.Text** to add tooltip only when ellipsis is found in antd. The [antd codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wd4tzm?file=/demo.tsx) is pretty self explanatory.

For a similar requirement, I added style changes to antd default tooltip and used Typography.Text for conditional display.

But if you require the antd Tooltip component itself, please refer [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124992/is-it-possible-to-show-an-ant-design-tooltip-conditionally-only-when-the-content). Worked for me for antd table component in a project with an older version of antd, where Typography.text did not have the tooltip along with ellipsis.